How to load only the language-specific .json with Weglot to prevent multiple animations loading simultaneously?
I use Weglot to translate a website into three languages. In the Hero section of the page, there is a JSON file that has three variants, one for each language. The correct JSON file should be displayed based on the current language.
I have applied CSS properties to show and hide the JSON file variants as follows:
/* English */
html:lang(en) .en-element {  
  height: auto !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
html:not([lang="en"]) .en-element {
  height: 0 !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

/* French */
html:lang(fr) .fr-element { 
  height: auto !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
html:not([lang="fr"]) .fr-element {
  height: 0 !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

/* Italian */
html:lang(it) .it-element { 
  height: auto !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
html:not([lang="it"]) .it-element {
  height: 0 !important;
  width: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

However, all JSON file variants are still loaded when the page is initially loaded. I expected that CSS alone could handle showing and hiding these files.
Question: How can I ensure that only the corresponding JSON file for the current language is loaded, and not all of them simultaneously? Is it possible to achieve this with CSS, or do I need to use a different approach?

If you're managing a subdomain or subdirectory-based integration, Weglot is able to replace the JSON file URL in the source (server-side) depending on the language to load the one you want according to the current language.

I've subdirectory integration. Do you mean that I need to use Weglot visual Editor and replace the source URL for JSONs?

With the subdirectory-based integration, by contacting their support, they will be able to replace the JSON file URL in the source, on a server-side way. You just need to provide them the website URL and the different JSON file URLs. This solution is only doable on their end on a server-side way.

I don’t think CSS alone can dynamically load resources, maybe try adding JavaScript.
Try this:
// Retrieve the current language from the HTML lang attribute
const currentLanguage = document.documentElement.lang;

// Select the JSON element corresponding to the current language
const jsonElement = document.querySelector(`.${currentLanguage}-element`);

// Loop through all JSON elements and hide them
document.querySelectorAll('[class$="-element"]').forEach(element => {
    element.style.display = 'none';
});

// Show the JSON element corresponding to the current language
jsonElement.style.display = 'block';

Put this JavaScript code after your HTML content or within a script tag in your HTML file. This script will hide all JSON elements and only display the one corresponding to the current language.
Don’t forget to replace .${currentLanguage}-element with the actual class name used for each JSON element in your HTML.
